# How is this SQL sub-query correctly vectorising?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, vectorization

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
  Code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  Budget decimal NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Employees (
  SSN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  Department INTEGER NOT NULL , 
  foreign key (department) references Departments(Code) 
)

INSERT INTO Departments(Code,Name,Budget) VALUES(14,'IT',65000);
INSERT INTO Departments(Code,Name,Budget) VALUES(37,'Accounting',15000);
INSERT INTO Departments(Code,Name,Budget) VALUES(59,'Human Resources',240000);
INSERT INTO Departments(Code,Name,Budget) VALUES(77,'Research',55000);

INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('123234877','Michael','Rogers',14);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('152934485','Anand','Manikutty',14);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('222364883','Carol','Smith',37);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('326587417','Joe','Stevens',37);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('332154719','Mary-Anne','Foster',14);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('332569843','George','O''Donnell',77);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('546523478','John','Doe',59);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('631231482','David','Smith',77);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('654873219','Zacary','Efron',59);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('745685214','Eric','Goldsmith',59);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('845657245','Elizabeth','Doe',14);
INSERT INTO Employees(SSN,Name,LastName,Department) VALUES('845657246','Kumar','Swamy',14);
```

Problem: "Select the names of departments with more than two employees."

[Wikibooks solution](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Exercises/Employee_management):

```
/*With subquery*/
SELECT D.Name FROM Departments D
  WHERE 2 < 
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Employees
     WHERE Department = D.Code
  );
```

My question: How does this solution work? That is, how does MSSQL know which values in `Departments` are to be kept from the sub-query? I can't see any way that the condition `WHERE Department = D.Code` can return a result that is ordered in a useful way to the outer query. I don't think that this is a fluke, I think that I just don't understand how SQL is vectorised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is called a *correlated subquery*.**

That is to say, the inner query is *correlated* to the outer one by use of an outer reference. In this case, that is `D.Code`. Therefore the subquery is being calculated *for every row* of `D`.

It's not a matter of *ordering*, in fact this query can return results in any order.  But the result from the subquery *must* be greater than `2` otherwise the `WHERE` predicate fails.

```sql
SELECT D.Name FROM Departments D  -- Departments has been aliased as D
  WHERE 2 < 
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Employees
     WHERE Department = D.Code    -- Here the inner query is being limited by
                                  -- the reference to the outer D table
  );
```

> I would probably use `... > 2` rather than `2 < ...`

> Side point: It's better to always use an explicit table reference in subqueries, eg `e.Department = D.Code`, because otherwise you could misspell a column and end up referring to an outer column instead of an inner column, and the correlation wouldn't work properly

Comment: Make that last point stronger. Always define a short (but not cryptic) alias for every table and use if for every column reference.

Comment: I was more explaining how it's important to always use a table reference, because of the danger of misspelling

Comment: The order must be important somehow. If there was no relationship between the order that the outer query works through `D` and the order that the inner query does the same, then the output would be nonsense. The only way that I could make sense of this is if the inner and outer queries are checking any specific given row in `D` at the same time.

Comment: Why does it need to do anything in a specific order? The inner query is *limited* by the `WHERE` clause referring to the outer query so it only counts matching rows from `Employees`, it makes no difference which *order* it does that check. It's the equivalent of running the *whole* subquery for every row of the outer query. Note that the compiler is free to physically reorder this query to get the same results, so this is only a high-level description